# Creating a dynamic js file and caching it?

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic

I have a JavaScript which is currently being re-used in over 5 websites, and will prolly be used by alot more websites as time progresses, the thing is - that javascript runs some checks according to the server name, and I was wondering what's the best way to create some JS file which has some server side variables in it, such as:

**js-functions.php:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   var myServer = <?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>;
</script>
```

as currently, this file will be downloaded every time, so how can I make it send out a 304 Unmodified, and use the browser caching to my advantage

Comment: Not sure what the question is? If you put the code above into the HTML page, and put the rest of the JS code into a static JS file and make it use `myServer`, the problem should be solved, shouldn't it?

Comment: Pekka - the thing is, I wouldn't be getting a 304 Unmodified, and the file would be downloaded each time.

Comment: Why would a static JS file be downloaded each time? I don't understand. Do you mean the HTML file or the JS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not create a dynamic JS file at all. If at all possible, put all the dynamic stuff into the main document; then load the main chunk of JavaScript from a static resource.

Put the code you already have into the `head` section of each HTML page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var myServer = "<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] ?>";
</script>
```

then link to a static JavaScript file:

```
<script src="http://domain.com/js/script.js">
```

inside the JavaScript file, do not use any PHP; use the `myServer` variable to do your checks.

The advantage of this is that if the web server is configured correctly, the static JS file will be loaded only once and you don't have to worry about caching.

You could even share the same JavaScript URL between all 5 sites.

Answer (score 4):

Use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule javascript.js javascript.php [L]
```

Name your php file `javascript.php` and direct your requests to `javascript.js`

Note: You need to set correct cache headers in your php file before sending any output

Comment: I don't understand how this addresses the issue? The PHP file will still be loaded on every request. This just gives the file a .js extension

Comment: @Pekka: As far as I know, BROWSER decides whether to download or not the file. php files are downloaded everytime

Comment: nope - if you use URL rewriting, no caching headers will be sent with the resource except those you actively set from within PHP.